# Javascript: Find in json array and push to array object if no key found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json array as:

```
  0: {Id: "1", name: "Adam", Address: "123", userId: "i98"}
  1: {Id: "2", name: "John", Address: "456"}
```

Now in the above array, the second one has no userId key available.

How can I loop through the above array and check if no userId key available then add the key with value 0. For eg add userId: "0"

What I have tried is the following:

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userData));

 for (const obj of jsonData) {
    var hasId = false;
      let objId = obj.find((o, i) => {
         if (o.userId === "userId") {
          hasId = true;
        }
      });
      if (!hasId) {
         obj.push();
       }
    }
```

But this gives me error:

```
obj.find is not a function
```

Any inputs to resolve my issue and push the key value to the array.

Comment: _"I have a json array"_ - No, that's an array of objects. JSON is a textual, language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your code, `obj` is an object and there is no `find` method on objects. If you want to check if an object has an array you can just `if( obj.userId )`

You can use `forEach` to loop thru the array.

```js
let jsonData  = [{Id: "1", name: "Adam", Address: "123", userId: "i98"},{Id: "2", name: "John", Address: "456"}];

jsonData.forEach(o => {
  o.userId = o.userId || 0; //Assign 0 if userId is undefined.
})

console.log(jsonData);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: it's not related but could you look at one of my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485838/angularjs-required-field-validation-and-highlight-for-dynamic-rows-of-html-tabl?noredirect=1#comment90010525_51485838 I am not getting any helpful replies on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) like the following way:

```js
var jsonData = [{Id: "1", name: "Adam", Address: "123", userId: "i98"},{Id: "2", name: "John", Address: "456"}]

jsonData = jsonData.map(i => {
  if(!i.hasOwnProperty('userId'))
    i.userId = 0;
  return i;
});

console.log(jsonData);
```